# .htaccess url rewriting rule for multiple php files

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i have about 100 php files and i want to rewrite their urls. 
They way i know to rewrite url for php file is something like

```
www.domain.com/article1/2
RewriteRule    ^article1/([0-9]+)/?$    article1.php?page=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle page requests
```

so like that for other files i have to write separate htaccess rules which will make file big and will take a lot of time to rewrite separate rule for every file. so i was think that is there anyway to rewrite these url for all files with single rule.

my urls are like

```
www.domain.com/article1.php?page=1
www.domain.com/photos.php?page=1
www.domain.com/tips.php?page=1
```

i would like to rewrite them to

```
www.domain.com/article1/1
www.domain.com/photos/1
www.domain.com/tips/1
```

i know with my above rule its possible but for that i have to use each rule for every file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably close to what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?page=$2 [END]
```

That setup will work in the http servers host configuration and in dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files), provided their interpretation is enabled at all (`AllowOverride` directive) and that the file is located at the correct location and readable for the http server.

If you are operating a really old version of the apache http server you may have to replace the `END` flag with the `L` flag...

---

A general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: any idea how to show get variable in url too like : www.domain.com/photos/page/1

Comment: Sure, that is the standard usage of rewriting rules. You can do that yourself. Look at the patterns in the `RewriteRule` and find the correspondence between the bracket pairs (`(...)`) and the placeholders (`$1` and `$2`). You have to add another rewrite rule for longer patterns, place that more special one _before_ the more general one, so exception before general rule.

Comment: ok thanks :) : : RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$           worked so all the time i was confused by ?$  :) it mean end of string .

Comment: `$` anchors the expression to the end of the subject, yes. The `?` makes the `/` optional. There are good books about regular expressions. Well worth reading ;-)